# Removing from an ArrayList gives me java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

In this android game, I'm using an ArrayList to keep track of all of the entities currently on the screen. Running through the list allows me to successfully update and add entities to the screen / list, but attempting to remove them gives me a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error. I'm a novice programmer, so I don't really know what could be going wrong.

The method I'm using to determine when a entity needs to be removed ( when it goes offscreen, but only through the top ) is this.

```
private void deleteEntities() {
    for(Entity ent : entsOnLevel) {
        if((ent.getY() + ent.getImage().getHeight()) < 0) {
            this.entsOnLevel.remove(ent);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me what could be going wrong?

Comment: @mirco.widmer Same exception, different cause. So not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

You created an iterator and you are removing his current item, hence he cant find the next item.

Read more here -> [ConcurrentModificationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444391/concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: Look at [the description of fail-fast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast). You can explicitly loop on the `Iterator` (instead of implicitly with an enhanced `for` loop) and call `it.remove()`.

Comment: this answer should be a close-as-duplicate vote

Answer (score 2):

You should remove an element from a List using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
    Iterator<YourDataType> it = YourList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) 
           it.remove();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection) should give you some hints, why you should use an Iterator.

Comment: Using an iterator to remove from the list doesn't seem to work, even if I use your code exactly in a method that get's updated constantly.

Comment: Updated constantly from different Threads or just called multiple times?

Comment: It's called with the game loop, so about 60 times a second the method is called.

Comment: I figured it out. I realized that I should probably update the iterator every time I want to use it, huh?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing `ConcurrentModificationException`  because you are  doing two operations on the same `list` at a time. i.e looping and removing  same time.

Inorder to avoid this situation use Iterator,which guarantees you to remove the element from list safely ...

Ex:

```
List<Object> objs;
Iterator<Object> i = objs.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Object o = i.next();
  //some condition
    i.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there must have been something wrong with just straight up removing data from a list! I guess I should go read up on Iterators, huh? Should I use something similar for my update method, or is safe to do it the way I was trying to do the removal method?

Comment: @JasonJahn A thumb rule here is `If you are modifying a Collection object while looping on it`,use iterator.

Comment: It don't know if I'm using the iterator wrong, but using this method in place of my old one, with an enhanced for loop, stopped my entities from updating.

  while (it.hasNext()) {
   Entity ent = it.next();
   ent.update();
  }

Comment: In such case ,You are updating the entity ,Not collection.So do not use Iterator there.Use a normal foreach loop and update your entity.Updating collection means,Adding and /remove from it

Comment: That's odd, because remove from the collection doesn't seem to be working either. 

 private void deleteEntities() {
  while (it.hasNext()) {
   Entity ent = it.next();
   if(ent.getY() < 800) {
    it.remove();
   }
  }
 }

I've never used stackoverflow before, is there somewhere else I should be discussing this?